# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 - Auto generating ID inside a text box

Tags: vb.net

I would like to add details to my table (sales table) where the sales ID starts from "SS1" and increments after each update. How do I code such that the vb does not crash when the table is still empty?

```
Private Function generate_id() As String
    '   Dim lastid As String = run_sql_query("SELECT MAX(FLD_ORDER_ID) AS LASTID FROM TBL_ORDER_A167640").Rows(0).Item("LASTID")
    '  Dim newid As String = "OR" & Mid(lastid, 3) + 1
    'Return newid
End Function
```

The code inserted will crash if the table is empty for say I wish to start from SS1. Please help ! :(

Comment: Use `run_sql_query("SELECT MAX(FLD_ORDER_ID) AS LASTID FROM TBL_ORDER_A167640")` and then check if it has any rows before trying to access `Rows(0)`. Also, what would you want `newid` to be if there are no rows?

Comment: So lets say i detect that the database (microsoft access) has no rows. How should i code so that it generates the ID?  I wanted the "newid" to generate my new sales id starting from S1 and so on

Comment: 1) The easy way is to add a row to the table when the table is created. 2) What is the type returned by `run_sql_query()`?

Comment: Forget the SS and just use the auto-number available in Access.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m not wrong in what you want, a way to do that might be:

```
Private Function generate_id() As String
        Dim lastid As Integer = CInt(run_sql_query("SELECT COUNT(FLD_ORDER_ID) AS LASTID FROM TBL_ORDER_A167640").Rows(0).Item("LASTID")) + 1
        Return "S1_" & CStr(lastid)
End Function
```

However is better to use an autoincremental ID/index as prefix numeric for your new id after “S1_”. Like this  `“S1_” & Select MAX( [autoncrementalID] ) as NUMID`  ....

Comment: What happens when you delete a record?

Comment: In a multi-user environment what happens if other users insert several records between the time that you retrieve Count and you do your insert?

Comment: I hope this is not the case. In scenarios that you describes a method like this is useless. Obviously OP need to create an autoincrement id and use that in concatenation with some string as OP want to create another VARCHAR id.
I hope he know that.